# dropdown change event to be bound with state, unordered list and button visibility with api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component, which has a dropdown, a button and an unordered list, I did bind the dropdown on change event to a function in the component, in that function I am trying to assign the state with the selected item, but for some reason assignment is not working properly, I am trying to alert both the selected items value and the assigned value into the state, but for some reason the alert of the state value is coming in correctly, it shows the previous selected items value. Am I missing something.

1. I want to change the visibility of the download button depending upon the selected items value, for example, selected items value is '' or empty string, then button should not be visible.
2. And the function of the changeEvent, should call an api method which takes the value of the selected community, that method returns a collection for the selected community of the dropdown. If this api call doesn't fetch values or the collection doesn't have any items in it, the download button should be invisible, if it has items then it would be visible.
3. For every item in the point # 2s api call, we should display an unordered item which come with editable checkbox.

Can anybody please suggest me for something from the below Code - thanks in advance.

```
class AccessData extends React.Component {
state = {
    files: [],
    communities: [],
    selectedCommunity: { display: 'Select a Community...', value: '' },
    communityValidationError: ""
 }

componentDidMount() {
    let env = clientConfiguration['Environment'];
    let x = `communitiesApi.${env}`;
    alert(clientConfiguration[x]);

    fetch(clientConfiguration['communitiesApi.local'])
        .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
      .then(data => {
            let communitiesFromApi = data.map(community => { return { value: community, display: community } })
            this.setState({ communities: [{ value: '', display: 'Select a Community...' }].concat(communitiesFromApi) });
 })
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    });
  }

handleDDLCommunityChange = (event) => {
    alert(event.target.value);
    this.setState({
        selectedCommunity: event.target.value
    });

    alert(this.state['selectedCommunity'].display);
 }

render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <div className="container">
        <div className="aqview-section">

        <div id="download_tool">
          <form id="download_form" method="post">
            <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <div className="header-box">
                <h2>Data Download Tool</h2>
              </div>
              <select id="communityName" title="Select a Community" name="communityName" onChange={"this.handleDDLCommunityChange.bind(this")} value={"this.state.selectedCommunity"}>
                {this.state.communities.map((community) => <option key={"community.value"} value={"community.value"}>{community.display}</option>)}
              </select>
              <div id="file_list_box">
                <p>
                  <strong>Data Files</strong>
                </p>
                <ul id="file_listing">
                  <li>Please select a community to display available files.</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <button id="download" styles="display: none;">Download</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
);
}
}

export default connect()(AccessData);
```

Answer (score 0):

The alert from the state value is showing you the previous selected value because setState does not always happens instantly. Assuming that rest of the code is working correctly, try passing your alert call as a second parameter to the setState method.

Like this:

```
handleDDLCommunityChange = (event) => {
alert(event.target.value);
/*this.setState({
selectedCommunity: event.target.value
});
alert(this.state['selectedCommunity'].display);*/
this.setState({
selectedCommunity: event.target.value
},() => {alert(this.state['selectedCommunity'].display)};
);
```

Comment: Hi, I did try it the same way you said, but still it gives me the previous value for one time and the it says undefined. Here is that part of code                                                             handleDDLCommunityChange = (event) => {
        alert(event.target.value);
        /*this.setState({
        selectedCommunity: event.target.value
        });
        alert(this.state['selectedCommunity'].display);*/
        this.setState({
            selectedCommunity: event.target.value
        },
            alert(this.state['selectedCommunity'].display)
        );
    }

Comment: This is how I am binding the dropdown events with the dropdown and state:                                                <select id="communityName" title="Select a Community" name="communityName" onChange={this.handleDDLCommunityChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.selectedCommunity}>
                                            {this.state.communities.map((community) => <option key={community.value} value={community.value}>{community.display}</option>)}
                                        </select>

Comment: The state is being set incorrectly hence undefined is thrown. Here's a modified SandBox of the above code https://codesandbox.io/embed/1-react-hello-world-v8ig5.

The selectedCommunity field in your state object expects an object with two fields value and display but upon doing setState the selectedCommunity is being overwritten to a normal string instead of an object. 

Also necessary changes were made in <select /> element as well. Refer to the SandBox for the same.

Comment: Hi Parichay Agrawal, I did exactly as you did, but did you see, after you change the item in the dropdown list, still always it shows to the "Select a community" option, can you please rectify that option - thank a lot buddy.

Comment: change the 'value' prop of <select> tag from this.state.selectedCommunity to this.state.selectedCommunity.display and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question, setState modifies the state asynchronously. 
So using this.state directly after calling setState won't give you the new state. 
Instead, setState takes a second parameter which is a function that will be called once the state change has been committed, like this:

```
   handleDDLCommunityChange = (event) => {
    alert(event.target.value);
    this.setState({
        selectedCommunity: event.target.value
    }, () => {
      alert(this.state['selectedCommunity'].display);
    });
   }
```

Note:

In the code you pasted you're adding string quotes when you shouldn't. You can think of the curly braces in JSX as "break out of HTML mode and go to JavaScript". So when you want to bind a JS value to a HTML attribute it's enough to do:

```
<option key={community.value}>
```

Where community is a JS variable in the current scope (inside your Render function, same as this)

For your other questions:

1) At the start of your render function you can check your conditions for if the button should be displayed or not and save it into a variable:

```
const shouldShowButton = // Logic that checks
```

Then in your render you can do:

```
<button id="download" styles={{ display: shouldShowButton ? 'block' : 'none' }} >Download</button>
```

The style attribute takes an object, hence the double curly braces. Another option is using https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames.

2) In your handleDDLCommunityChange function you can use something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch, like:

```
fetch(/* endpointURL/?community= event.target.value /*).then( /* setState */)
```

And then use the value in state inside render to set the value for shouldShowButton

3) Assuming that you're saving the resulting list of communities in your state, that will trigger a re-render so you should be able to simply map over those items in state, the same way you do with your select. This is a key pattern in React, render a UI, respond to user interaction and store results of that interaction in state, and re-render.